# Windows 10 удаление встроенных приложений через PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

Хочу удалить на нескольких ПК, встроенные приложения Windows 10 через PowerShell,
нарыл команды

```
DISM /Online /Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages | select-string Packagename

DISM /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_18.2002.1101.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

и все работает, но только пока удаляешь с одного ПК, на втором если версия отличается то выходит ошибка.
Думал использовать знак "*" типа -

```
DISM /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub*
```

однако не работает.

Подскажите как можно унифицировать команду на удаление, чтобы независимо от версии можно было удалять?

Comment: Скорее всего никак. Или же каким-то способом выяснять в скрипте точное имя пакета и передавать его команде.

Comment: эх, тоска печаль. Я наверное тогда просто по версиям про бомблю, если нет то пролетаем если есть то кил алл

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный проект [Win10 Initial Setup Script](https://github.com/Disassembler0/Win10-Initial-Setup-Script). Набор настроек для тюнинга той или иной части Windows 10.

### Чем проект крут

- **Не**интерактивность. Пишем в свой скрипт нужные фунции и оно дёргается. Нахрен мышки и Visual Basic с `sendkey`.
- На каждую функцию есть противоположная, которая возвращает "всё взад". Это даже прописано в правилах добавления новых фич. Хочешь добвить свою суперкрутую тюнилку - сделай и rollback для неё.
- Всё ещё развивается. Важный пункт, потому что не надо спровождать и менйтейнирить самому.

### Чем проект плох

- **Не**интерактивность. Пишем в свой скрипт нужные фунции и оно дёргается. Нет 3d лабиринтов, которые надо пролететь на космолёте, чтобы отрубить автозапуск.
- Нет идемпотентности. Если интегрируем с `ansible` - всегда будет `changed`.
- Нет поддержки windows 7. Какие-то общие ветки реестра безусловно будут меняться, но всё же.

Теперь конкретно по проблеме встроенных прог. Есть функция, которая называется [UninstallMsftBloat](https://github.com/Disassembler0/Win10-Initial-Setup-Script/blob/master/Win10.psm1#L2893). Соответственно, согласно [документации](https://github.com/Disassembler0/Win10-Initial-Setup-Script#advanced-usage), надо написать:

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Win10.ps1 -include Win10.psm1 UninstallMsftBloat
```

Comment: Приветствую достопочтенный дон Румата ( Эсторский?) ). Однако в этом скрипте предлагается выполнять `Get-AppxPackage "AppxPackageName" | Remove-AppxPackage` увы, она удаляет только в том профиле из которого выполняется. И если зайти под новым профилем на этом ПК, то приложения будут снова установлены.

Comment: К сожалению это так. Я сам страдаю, потому что в той винде, которую я ставлю - несколько пользователей, а на работе - вообще домен и 2к учёток. Выход я вижу только один - `runonce` для нового пользователя.

Comment: `Эсторский?` Он самый. Пойду поем вепря Ы, а то после этих балов со всякими донами Оканами дико хочется жрать.

Comment: [К сожалению это так. Я сам страдаю, потому что в той винде, которую я ставлю - несколько пользователей, а на работе - вообще домен и 2к учёток. Выход я вижу только один - runonce для нового пользователя.] Вопрос, а с вами где-то можно пообщаться, в личке?

Comment: В профиле написан jabber. Можно туда.